# The system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, xorg

I upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04. After I reboot i met "the system is running in low graphic".

my graphics driver is amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.

After I remove the driver I can get into the system, but only see wallpaper, but can use terminal but can't switch, and  can't move either, and system crash information always pop out.

My xorg.conf

> Section "ServerLayout"
>
> > Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
> >     Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
> >     EndSection
>
> Section "Module"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>
> > Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
> >      Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
> >      Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
> >      Option      "DPMS" "true"
> >     EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>
> > Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
> >      Driver      "fglrx"
> >      BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
> >     EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>
> > Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
> >      Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
> >      Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
> >      DefaultDepth     24
> >      SubSection "Display"
> >      Viewport   0 0
> >      Depth     24
> >      EndSubSection
> >     EndSection

$ glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

I have tried many ways that i found, but i can't work out, all day. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: What is your VGA and OS?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]    I reinstall the system.  Anyway thanks.